# How to detect grade level and react to it, in Java

Tags: java

```
    int result = 65;
    char grade;

    if (result >= 90 ) {
        grade = 'A';
    } else if (result >= 80) {
        grade = 'B';
    } else if (result >= 70) {
        grade = 'C';
    } else if (result >= 60) {
        grade = 'D';
    } else {
        grade = 'F';

    }

    System.out.println("You got grade " + grade);
}
```

}

I'm trying to write a program that if the student gets grade 'F', I would like the program to write that they need to re-sit the exam. How can I do this? Thanks

I was thinking of first using Character.toString(); and also .equals(); but these two need a string.

Comment: Use a [Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html).

Comment: You can check `grade` variable value using if-else after `if-else` ladder. Like `if(grade=='F'){}else{}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to what you already did.

```
if (grade == 'F') {
   System.out.println("You have to retake the exam");
}
```

The `equals()` method is needed to compare String because they are objects but you can use `==` to compare chars, since they are primitive types.